# why leafpad cannot display compose contents from /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8

Tags: debian, text-processing, compose-key

I tried to view the file Compose from /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8 using -

usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8$ leafpad Compose

[image]

and got the following sort of blank page. I know it's not blank because the line numbers can be seen on the left-hand side but it seems incredible that I cannot see/view the contents on the editor. On the console/terminal emulator the compose keybinds can be seen perfectly but NOT on leafpad. Does anybody know why ?

Edit - I used Dejavu Sans Mono as that is one of the fonts which is supposed to have quite a bit of the unicode font coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The first 48 lines are empty, you can check that with `hexdump`:

```
$ hexdump -C /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | head -3
00000000  0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a  0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a  |................|
*
00000030  23 20 55 54 46 2d 38 20  28 55 6e 69 63 6f 64 65  |# UTF-8 (Unicode
```

Comment: I do wonder though why the first 48 lines are empty, any thoughts on that ?

Comment: @shirish The empty lines seem to be a side effect added when the locale files are built from templates, they don't carry any semantic meaning. See e.g. the [template](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-libX11/blob/master/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre) of the file in question, as you can see, no empty lines are present yet. If I was *really* curious what part of the build process added them, I would start my investigation with X11's make files, [this one](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/master/nls/Makefile.am) in particular.